# sklearn r2_score and python stats lineregress function give very different values of R^2. Why?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, linear-regression

I´m using the same data but different python libraries to calculate the coefficient of determination R^2. Using stats library and sklearn yield different results.

**What is the reason behind this behavior?**

```
# Using stats lineregress
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
print r_value**2
```

0.956590054918

```
# Using sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print r2_score(x, y)
```

0.603933484937

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `r_value` returned by `linregress` is the correlation coefficient *r* of *x* and *y*. In general, the squared correlation coefficient *r²* is not the same as the coefficient of determination *R²*.

The coefficient of determination tells you how well a model fits the data. Thus, `r2_score` thinks that *x* are the true values and *y* are values predicted by a model.

If your *x* and *y* are true and predicted data, *R²* is what you want. However, if both are measured data you most likely want *r²* instead.

Details about the [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) and the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) can be found at Wikipedia.